How to setup docker rootless compose with apache php image and bind mount? (file owner)
i try to get this to work:

os is debian based
docker image: php:7.4-apache
php application code is copied to image on build
compose

bind mount a sub-folder in the application directories for manipulation on host



the bind-mouted folder on the host is needed for two reasons:

i try to replicate an old dockerless server setup
the folder contains client specific

configuration-files
client uploaded data
template files
data generated by the php app (pdf files) (from the template-files


to do this someone login in to the host and changes the files / uploads them via sftp
backup management (the server is backed up and so these folders too...)

the docker setup is running in rootless mode and the user has also no root privileges (no sudo)
i first tried to setup the image so that i add a user that is identical to host (name and ids)
and change the APACHE_RUN_USER & GROUP to this user.
that did work on a normal root docker setup.
but not on the rootless setup.
(as there the id-s are translated)
i then tried to just set the APACHE_RUN_USER to root but apache barked on me that this is a very bad idea…
What is the best-practice to setup something like this?

i have full control over the docker-images
no control over the linux and docker environment
(so no super-user and docker-rootless is given)

the only other idea that came to my mind would be to setup a ssh-proxy like thing on the host machine and create a ssh /sftp login in the docker image.
than i could change the binding to a docker-managed volume.
i cross-posted this question at
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-setup-docker-rootless-compose-with-the-apache-php-image-and-bind-mount-file-owner/141996

Can you [edit] the question to include some more details on what you're trying to do and why you need the host directory?  The very best practice is to remove the bind mount entirely and store the data somewhere else, like a database; failing that, general common practice is to set the container user or group ID to something that can access the files; and avoid using a bind mount to provide your application code, ignoring Docker's image system.

i know that it is best-practice to have docker-managed volumes.
i have added some more dedtails

Not the solution but you could open that file in vim or nano editor inside docker and edit it. Why don't you mount read only volumes for the config files? Are those files edited inside docker? If not then you could use read only volumes and don't worry about permission at all (I think)

i added some more information on the folder usage.
we are on the way to rewrite the hole application.. but that will take a bunch of time and we just now need some in-between working solution that needs as little as possible changes to the code base...
but as i added in the answer - one way i can think of is to manage to setup a ssh or sftp login inside the container so i can use a normal volume....
i then only have to check how i can manage the backup process in a smooth and simple enough way...

I've generally read the Docker documentation as being extremely enthusiastic about named volumes, but bind mounts work just fine (unless you're storing your entire application there, and unless you're on some specific host-OS setups where they're slow) and if you do need to directly manipulate the files, I'd suggest just using a bind mount.
